# regular expression matching a string that is followed with another string without capturing the latter

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Is there an ability to make a lookahead assertion non-capturing? Things like `bar(?:!foo)` and `bar(?!:foo)` do not work (Python).

Comment: Lookaheads *are* non-capturing.  Are you perhaps looking for *negative* lookahead?  That's just `(?!foo)`. [ref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `bar(?=ber)`
on "barber", "bar" is matched, but "ber" is not captured.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't respond to Alan's question, but I'll assume that he's correct and you're interested in a negative lookahead assertion.  IOW - match 'bar' but NOT 'barfoo'.  In that case, you can construct your regex as follows:

```
myregex =  re.compile('bar(?!foo)')

for example, from the python console:

>>> import re
>>> myregex =  re.compile('bar(?!foo)')
>>> m = myregex.search('barfoo')
>>> print m.group(0)                <=== Error here because match failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
>>> m = myregex.search('bar')    
>>> print m.group(0)                <==== SUCCESS!
bar
```